# Draw coterminal rotation angles with pstricks

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, arc

How draw the rotation of coterminal angles at 135 degree with pstricks, as a shown in figure.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-3.5,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{<->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(3,3)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\psline[linewidth=2pt](2;135)(0,0)(2,0)
\psarcn[linewidth=2pt]{->}{1.75}{0}{135}
\psparametricplot[arrows=->]{0}{495}{
     t 1000 div 1 add t cos mul 
     t 1000 div 1 add t sin mul }
% \psparametricplot[arrows=->,algebraic]{0}{Pi 2.75 mul}{% algebraic version
%     (t/15 +1)*cos(t) | (t/15 +1)*sin(t) }
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]